# converting csv to json and then parsing it in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a python script which converts a csv file to json.

```py
import csv
import json

# Function to convert a CSV to JSON
# Takes the file paths as arguments
def make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    
    # create a dictionary
    data = {}
    
    # Open a csv reader called DictReader
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)
        
        # Convert each row into a dictionary
        # and add it to data
        for rows in csvReader:
            
            # Assuming a column named 'No' to
            # be the primary key
            key = rows['issue']
            data[key] = rows

    # Open a json writer, and use the json.dumps()
    # function to dump data
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
        
# Driver Code

# Decide the two file paths according to your
# computer system
csvFilePath = r'Names.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'Names.json'

# Call the make_json function
make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

my csv file is like this

```
issue, summary, desc
A1, summ1, desc1
A2, summ2, desc2
```

Once the script is run, I get the following json file

```json
{
    "A1": {
        "issue": "A1",
        " summary": " summ1",
        " desc": " desc1"
    },
    "A2": {
        "issue": "A2",
        " summary": " summ2",
        " desc": " desc2 "
    }
}
```

Now in my javascript application, I want to read this json file and iterate over it. Sample code in my react application is

```js
import myData from <jsonfile>
console.log(myData['A1'].summary)
```

but for this to work I need to know the value A1, A2 etc..

I am unable to work out how to iterate on this. Please can someone guide me on what a sample javascript code should look like to work with this json.
Operations I want to perform are extract, all issue fields, extract all summary fields etc. Basically work on this json result like it was an array.

Comment: Did you try a JSON.parse(file_contents) on the JS side once you got the string in?

Comment: Simpler to iterate and filter if you send as js array structure. `[{"issue": "A1"...},{"issue": "A2"...}]` unless you need those object keys to do o(1) lookups also

Comment: Why didn't you trim the `" summary"` and `" desc"` keys?

Comment: `for...in` will let you iterate over it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

`Object.keys(myData)` will give you just the keys

Comment: @charlietfl I don't need the object keys for lookup, so you are suggesting I rewrite my python script and convert array instead. Let me give that a try.

Comment: Yes. You can also convert what you have to same array using `Object.values()` but would be needless step vs sending in preferred structure

Comment: @user7290573 your comment has helped my use-case, using Object.keys I can fetch all the keys and then I can easily iterate over using those values.

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (const k in myData) {
    console.log(`${myData[k].issue}: ${myData[k][" summary"]}`);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have spaces in your JSON names:
you have
`" summary"` instead of `"summary"`.
Fix that, and it will work.